# Ubuntu 15.04 Gray Boxes Over scroll Bars, and Multi-line boxes

Tags: 15.04, ide

So, I've had this issue happen a lot, especially when trying to develop using Bluefish IDE, and gray boxes are in my working space, and it makes it an extreme nuisance.

When this issue happens in a smaller window, the gray boxes cover almost everything.

Here is a small example:

[image]

[image]

I hope you guys can tell what the issue is, and I hope you know how to fix it.

(If you look in the text editor portion of the IDE, you will see the gray boxes over the white text area.

I have an intel processor using hd 4400 graphics.

Comment: have the exact same issue

Comment: I hope someone can help us, because it is very annoying, and most of the time it is a GREAT hindrance to my workflow.